# How to use databasehelper class in an asynctask class working on a different class

Tags: java, android, database, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

Hi everybody I was stuck at a point, the problem is that I have three classes shown below and I want to instantiate my DatabaseHelper class in AsyncTask class. Could you please help, how can I get context in AsyncTask class?

**Problem Solved**

1. MainActivity class

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ...
   FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();
   fetchData.execute();
   ...
   }
   ```
2. DatabaseHelper

   ```
   public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   ....
   public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   ....
   }
   ```
3. FetchData class

   ```
   public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   ....
   DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(); //need context here!!!
   ....
   }
   ```

#

Thanks to Kasra, I create a fourh class and use it in MainActivity before calling AsyncTask

4. ContextStatic class

   ```
   public class ContextStatic {
   private static Context mContext;

   public static Context getmContext() {
       return mContext;
   }
   public static void setmContext(Context mContext) {
       ContextStatic.mContext = mContext;
   }
   }
   ```

**Updated MainActivity class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    ContextStatic.setmContext(this);
    FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();
    fetchData.execute();
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
     protected Long doInBackground(Context... c) {
         Context myContext = c[0];
// Do your things here....
     }


     protected void onPostExecute() {
// Insert your post execute code here
     }
 }
```

You can call this AsyncTask by the following line - assuming you are in an activity:

```
 new FetchData().execute(this);
```

---

if You cannot change your AsyncTask deceleration, then you can try using a static variable - although it is not as efficient and pretty as AsyncTask deceleration. Try this:

```
Class myStatic{
private  static Context mContext;


static public void setContext(Context c);
mContext = c;
}

static public Context getContext(){
return mContext;
}

}
```

and in your main code, before you call AsyncTask, call this:

```
myStatic.setContext(this);
```

in your doInBackground method of your AsyncTask, add this:

```
Context myContext = myStatic.getContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay Kasra, but this will not work for me because my asynctask class declaration is `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`. Do you have any other suggestion?